# How to use same Laravel 8 backend to both ReactJS and React Native to save data to MySql database

Tags: mysql, reactjs, react-native, laravel-8

I want to save the name, email, phone number to MySql database with Laravel 8 back end.
I want to create both Web page and Mobile app.
Web page is done. I did it with ReactJS and Laravel.
But Mobile app is I can't save to MySql database with Laravel.
I think I don't know how to send input data to back end in React Native. So, how can i send data on post method to same back end.

**ReactJS code**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import swal from 'sweetalert';


class Register extends Component{

    state = {
        name: '',
        email: '',
        phone: '',
        
    }
    handleInput = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        })
    }

    savereg = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const res = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/add-driver', this.state);

        if (res.data.status === 200) {
            swal({
                title: "Success!",
                text: res.data.message,
                icon: "success",
                button: "Ok!",
              });
    
              this.props.history.push('/add-driver');
    
               this.setState({
                name: '',
                email: '',
                phone: '',
               });
            
        }else {
            console.log('something wrong');
        }
    }



    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                
              <div className="container">
                  <h1>Zihan</h1>
                <form onSubmit={this.savereg}>
                    <div className="form-group mb-3">
                        <label>Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name='name' onChange={this.handleInput} value={this.state.name} className='form-control' />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group mb-3">
                        <label>email</label>
                        <input type="text" name='email' onChange={this.handleInput} value={this.state.email} className='form-control' />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group mb-3">
                        <label>Phone</label>
                        <input type="text" name='phone' onChange={this.handleInput} value={this.state.phone} className='form-control' />
                    </div>
                    <div className='form-group mb-3'>
                        <button type='submit' className='btn btn-primary'>Save</button>
                     </div>
                </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Register;
```

**React Native code**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Button } from 'react-native';


/*
const ModelPopup = ({visible, children}) => {

}
*/
export default class Login extends React.Component {

  state = {
    name: '',
    email: '',
    phone: '',
   // error_list: [],
}
handleInput = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
}

saveStudent = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const res = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/add-student', this.state);

    if(res.data.status === 200)
    {
      

        this.setState({
         name: '',
         email: '',
         phone: '',
        });
    }else {
        this.setState({
         error_list: res.data.validate_err,
     });
    }
}

  
  render(){
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.logo}>Register here</Text>
        <Text></Text>
        
        
        <View style={styles.inputView} >
          <TextInput  
            style={styles.inputText}
            placeholder="Name" 
            placeholderTextColor="#92A9BD"
            id='name'
          name='name'
            onChangeText={text => this.setState({name:text})}/>
        </View>
        
        <View style={styles.inputView} >
          <TextInput  
            
            style={styles.inputText}
            placeholder="email" 
            placeholderTextColor="#92A9BD"
            id='email'
          name='email'
            onChangeText={text => this.setState({email:text})}/>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.inputView} >
          <TextInput  
            
            style={styles.inputText}
            placeholder="phone" 
            placeholderTextColor="#92A9BD"
            id='phone'
          name='phone'
            onChangeText={text => this.setState({phone:text})}/>
        </View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.saveStudent} style={styles.loginBtn}>
          <Text style={styles.loginText}>Submit</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 
  logo:{
    fontWeight:"bold",
    fontSize:50,
    color:"#5800FF",
    //marginBottom:70
  },
  loginBtn:{
    width:"50%",
    backgroundColor:"#548CFF",
    borderRadius:20,
    height:50,
    alignItems:"center",
    justifyContent:"center",
    marginTop:40,
    marginBottom:10
  },
  inputText:{
    height:50,
    color:"black"
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#A2D2FF',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  buton1: {
      //backgroundColor: "#98EAF6"
     // color: "#0F1718",
     //marginTop: 20
  },
  tex1: {
    color: "#98EAF6"
  },
  inputText:{
    height:50,
    color:"black"
  },
  
});
```

**Laravel RegisterController code**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Register;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request){
          $register = new Register;
          $register->name = $request->input('name');
          $register->email = $request->input('email');
          $register->phone = $request->input('phone');
          $register->save();

          return response()->json([
              'status'=> 200,
              'message'=> 'Saved to database successfully',
          ]);

    }
}
```

React JS front end and Laravel back end are working. React Native frontend and laravel backend is not working.

How can I send data on `post` method?

Comment: Have you checked the Laravel logs? You might to try adding some logs to the store controller to check your receiving the data as expected? Also, what happens in the React Native code after the request is sent? What status code do you receive back?

Comment: I can't upload image. 
module "D:/My Projects/Mobile App/React Native/Software Project/popup/Mypopup2/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/Data/LogBoxLog"
'LogLevel' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)
'import type' declarations can only be used in TypeScript files.ts(8006)

this folder shows error.

Comment: That's not exactly what I meant. The laravel/backend logs will be in storage/logs/laravel.log - You can also log your request in your controller with something like Log::info('My Logs', [$request->all()]). You should also try catching the axios request to see if it's throwing an error in React native with something like axios.post().catch((error) => console.log(error));

Comment: I think Laravel is not wrong. Laravel is working with ReactJs web app. But the React Native is the wrong. When i clicked the submit button even without input also I got same error.

Comment: Then you need to log or catch the error in React Native, or at least say what the error is. Have you noticed that the API route in your example is different than the one in React? /add-driver vs /add-student?

Comment: yeah. I have change the React Native code now. But still have error. Now I'm getting that "typeerror: network request failed"

Comment: constructor()
    {
        super();
        this.state={
            name:'',
            email:'',
            phone:''
        }
    }

Comment: submit()
    {
       let collection={}
       collection.name=this.state.name,
       collection.email=this.state.email,
       
       console.warn(collection);

       var url = 'https://127.0.0.1:8000/api/add-driver';

       fetch(url, {
           method: 'post',
           body: JSON.stringify(collection),
           headers: new Headers({
               'Content-Type': 'application/json'
           })
       }).then(res => res.json())
       .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
       .then(response => console.log('Success:', response));

    }

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71246166/16318779
please go through this link, I said clearly about the error.